# Rounding fairness optimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem which is simple to state, and would like to know if there is a smart solution rather than crude calculation.

Given the following vector `A <- c(30,20,150,50,30,70)` which sums to 350, I need to distribute (add) 5 additional units total to the elements, thereby yielding a sum of 355.

I am restricted to integer adjustments only. I wish to distribute these 5 units in order to minimize the maximum of the percent change in the element after adjustment. I.e., I wish the adjustments of each element to be "fairest", in that sense. For example, adding the vector

`c(0,0,3,0,0,2)` yields a "new" A (A.New) of: 30  20 153  50  30  72

The percentage change in each element (going from A to A.New) is:
0.000000 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000 2.857143
with a maximum change of **2.857143**

Evaluating again with an adjustment of
`c(0,0,4,0,0,1)` yields an A.New of 30  20 154  50  30  71
and percentage changes of 
0.000000 0.000000 2.666667 0.000000 0.000000 1.428571
with a maximum percentage change of **2.666667**

Therefore `c(0,0,4,0,0,1)` would be preferred (but not yet optimum.)

An adjustment of `c(0,0,3,1,0,1)` yields a minimum of maximum percentage change in the elements, of **2.000000**. This seems to be the optimal solution.

Concerning the case of repeated element values (ties), or indeed of all elements valued identically would suggest that I'd need to randomize the distribution of adjustments perhaps, or include a secondary criteria that would guide how best to distribute, which is just the nature of the beast given the constraints. But I'd have to handle these as special cases. One idea would be to jitter the repeated values in A randomly prior to solving, for example, then remove the jitter at the end. However, this is not a primary concern.

I've been looking at using `lpSolve` as a potential solution, but the objective function as "the min of a max of values" is problematic.

I could create a custom and probably complex algorithm for this, but maybe I have overlooked simpler ways to approach this?

(Note that in reality, the vector being adjusted can have many hundreds of elements, potentially.)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'minimize the maximum of the percent change in the element after adjustment. I.e., I wish the adjustments of each element to be "fairest"'. Please specify your desired outcome, e.g. c(31,20,151,51,31,71) OR c(30,20,155,50,30,70). What about ties?

Comment: @RHA is right ,when you edit this knowing how to handle ties would be very useful. (what if all 6 parts of the list were the same value).

Comment: I'll edit, thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I think it is a pity that this question is closed, because it is potentially a (very) good question. I have edited it to ask for a solution (and not a package). @DataCurious Can you add some code of what you tried with lpSolve?

Comment: @RHA: I haven't written any code yet, except a false start with lpSolve that was incorrect; hence my interest in suggestions for alternatives if lpSolve is really not the ticket, so to speak :) I'll update this question if I have developed a reasonable approach when I get to it, though. I also think it's actually an interesting question, thanks ...

Comment: Thanks very much for editing contributions, all :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using a matrix of the increase in percentages. I have put it into a function taking a vector 'x' and the number of integers 'N' you wish to add (for explanation see comments).

```
Allocate_Int <- function (x,N) { # x is vector, N = Number of Integers
  p <- 100/x # Percentage increase by 1 
  m <- p %o% c(1:N) # create a matrix of increased percentage
  m1 <- m <= m[order(m)][N] # find the N-th lowest numbers in T/F matrix  
  return(rowSums(m1)) # and return the nr of TRUE values per item.
  }
```

And it works with the example from your question:

```
A <- c(30,20,150,50,30,70)  
Allocate_Int(A,5)  
[1] 0 0 3 1 0 1
```

If there are ties, the returning vector has to many values:

```
Allocate_Int(c(1,1),3)
[1] 2 2
```

If you want to find the ties, use:

```
vec1 <- c(10,20,20,50,100)
N <- 10
Allocate_Int(vec1,N)-Allocate_Int(vec1,N-1)
[1] 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, it's compact and direct. Generating all possible combinations of solutions by constructing the matrix is perhaps a bit expensive for large numbers of elements in `x` and `1:N`, but in most the applications that matter to me `N` will not be that large, typically.

Comment: Also it shouldn't be difficult to reduce the matrix by trading off iteration for memory if really necessary (e.g., calculating each logical row in `m1` individually and summing the number of `TRUE` values along the way.)  Thank you!

Comment: @DataCurious Actually matrix operations in R are fast, even `Allocate_Int(1:1000,100)` doesn't take more than a second. If you feel your question has been answered, then please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the accept mark left of the answer.

Comment: I do consider it answered, and your solution was very helpful in seeing how compactly a set of potential solutions could be specified. Thanks to all for assisting in getting this question off of hold, it was much appreciated!